# Evaluate integral with radical in denominator

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm stuck on exactly how to start this integral. I notice it looks somewhat similar to the arcsin integral. but if that's the case, I'm not sure what substitution to make to get it there. Any tips in the right direction?

$$ \int_0^9 \frac{x^3}{\sqrt{81-x^2}}$$

Comment: Substitute $x=9\sin\theta$, so $dx=9\cos\theta d\theta$, and use trigonometric identities to simplify. You should get something with $\arcsin$ in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: start with $x=9t$, so the integral becomes
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{3^6t^3}{3^2\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,9dt=
3^6\int_0^1\frac{t^3}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,dt
$$
Then set $t=\sin u$.